# Example of a proper metric space such that the associated length space is not proper.

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

Can anyone give me a example of a proper metric space $(X,d)$ such that $(X,\bar d)$, where $\bar d$ is the induced length metric, is not proper.

I have a example but I am not sure if it is right. 
Ex-: $X\subset R^2$(plane) $X=[0,1]\times {0}\cup [0,1]\times {1}\cup {\frac{1}{n}}\times[0,1]$.This example can be found in BH book. 
Please comment.

Comment: This whole space is a closed ball, which is not compact, thus it is not proper.

Comment: Define proper metric space & induced length metric in it?

Comment: Can anyone give me a example of a proper metric space $(X,d)$ such that $(X,\bar d)$ is what?? Write question properly..

Comment: A space is proper is every closed bounded ball is compact.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric for induced length metric

Comment: I hope only people understand induced length metric answer this question and not to make unnecessary comment.

Comment: What I have got in wiki  If

$d_\text{I}(x,y)=d(x,y)$
for all points x and y in M, we say that (M, d) is a length space or a path metric space and the metric d is intrinsic.

Comment: @user152715: I have added two commas that should make the question easier to parse. Some peoples' English is better than others'; please be tolerant.

Comment: It will be 'an example' too. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $X=[0,1]\times\{0\}\cup\{0\}\times[0,1]\cup\{\frac{1}{n};n=1,2,\dots\}\times[0,1]$ works.
This planar set $X$ is a compact subset of a Euclidean space and therefore proper.
(This is not what you wrote but something similar. The rough idea is to have a comb where the spikes accumulate.)

The diameter of $X$ w.r.t. the length metric $\bar d$ is 3 (draw a figure!), so to show that $(X,\bar d)$ is not proper it suffices to show that it is not compact.
To this end, consider the following cover: $U_n=\{\frac1n\}\times(\frac13,1]$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, $U_0=\{0\}\times(\frac13,1]$ and $U_{-1}=X\cap([0,1]\times[0,\frac23))$.
These sets are an infinite open cover of $(X,\bar d)$ which has no proper subcover, so the space is not compact.

Note that the covering sets are not open in $(X,d)$ and there is no contradiction with its compactness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We can show the set is not compact by taking the infinite sequence ${(1/n,1/2)}$. It has no convergence sequence as the point cluster near (0,1/2) but do not converge as the distance from to the set is atleast 1. Is this ok ?

Comment: @user45170, that's ok as well. Sequential compactness and cover compactness are the same thing for metric spaces.